# Updating a panda df using a second df

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

My problem is that I have a dataframe (df1) with a `start` and `stop` column and then a `counter` column. I have a separate dataframe (df2) with a `value` and a `count` column. I want to find the row in df1 whose `start` and `stop` contains the `value` of df2 and then add the `count` of df2 to df1. The two dataframes will have different rows and will not be ordered.

I've written a loop going row by row through df2, but it's too slow so I was wondering if there was a type of join or merge that I could do. Thank you for your help.

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame()
df1['start'] = range(1,11)
df1['stop'] = range(2,12)
df1['count'] = [0]*10
#df1:
#   start  stop  count
#0      1     2      0
#1      2     3      0
#2      3     4      0
#3      4     5      0
#4      5     6      0
#5      6     7      0
#6      7     8      0
#7      8     9      0
#8      9    10      0
#9     10    11      0


df2 = pd.DataFrame()
df2['count'] = range(21,26)
df2['value'] = [x + 0.5 for x in range(1,6)]
#df2:
#   count  value
#0     21    1.5
#1     22    2.5
#2     23    3.5
#3     24    4.5
#4     25    5.5

#Line below doesn't work, throws:
#ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects
df1[df2[(df1.start < df2.value) & (df2.value < df1.stop)], 'count'] += df2.count

#desired update of df1:
#   start  stop  count
#0      1     2     21
#1      2     3     22
#2      3     4     23
#3      4     5     24
#4      5     6     25
#5      6     7      0
#6      7     8      0
#7      8     9      0
#8      9    10      0
#9     10    11      0
```

Comment: Are your intervals always length 1? If so, you can use np.floor() on the value column of df2 and then merge the 2 data frames on df1.start = d2.value. Then you can group by start and sum count

Comment: They are not always length 1

Comment: You can always merge the tables then update the count column using apply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- use `searchsorted` to find position to insert at.
- This works because your intervals not overlap but share an endpoint.
- It will assume a `6` goes into the interval `[6, 7)`.  This is dictated by the parameter `side='left'`
- Use `side='right'` to assume `6` goes in interval `(5, 6]`

---

```
df1.loc[
    df1.index[df1.start.searchsorted(df2.value) - 1],
    'count'
] += df2['count'].values

   start  stop  count
0      1     2     21
1      2     3     22
2      3     4     23
3      4     5     24
4      5     6     25
5      6     7      0
6      7     8      0
7      8     9      0
8      9    10      0
9     10    11      0
```